# django Localdate doesn't return correct date

Tags: django, datetime

I am running a django where i have some sort of conditions written based on the date.

My views.py file

```
from django.utils import timezone

def my_method(current_date=timezone.localdate()):
    logger.info(f"Current date is obtained as {current_date}")
```

Whenever i load the page, my views.py internally calls this method and the date doesn't gets updated daily.

In settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'PST8PDT'
USE_TZ = True
```

Irrespective of today's date, it always prints old dates and after few days the date gets updated to correct date and the same date gets continued for next 4-5 days.

What is that i am  doing wrong here ?
P.S. I have also tried using python's native datetime.date.today() which resulted in same abnormal behavior.

Comment: Are you sure your timezone format's working? Django's docs use UTC-styled dates, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE)

Comment: Because you pass a datetime object as default. Note that `timezone.localdate` is *not* re-evaluated in each call. It is evaluated once, and then *reused*.

Comment: @willem then what should be the way to do it?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 - even if timezone is incorrect at least the date should get changed. isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072235/django-localdate-doesnt-return-correct-date#comment111534952_63072235),

> Because you pass a datetime object as default. Note that `timezone.localdate` is not re-evaluated in each call. It is evaluated once, and then reused.

So, just change your function as,

```
from django.utils import timezone


def my_method(current_date=None):
    if current_date is None:
        current_date = timezone.localdate()
    print(current_date)
```

### Example

```
In [1]: # suppose we have a function like this,                                                                                                                                                                    

In [2]: from datetime import datetime
...:
...:
...: def foo(default=datetime.utcnow()):
    ...:     return default
...:

In [3]: # and I am calling this 'foo' again and again and again                                                                                                                                                    

In [4]: # and expecting to return different value each time                                                                                                                                                        

In [5]: foo()
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 1, 48, 30, 525369)

In [6]: foo()
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 1, 48, 30, 525369)

In [8]: # see there is no evaluation happening.                                                                                                                                                                    

In [9]: #                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [10]: # So, I have changed the function to ,                                                                                                                                                                    

In [11]: def foo(default=None):
    ...:     if default is None:
        ...:         default = datetime.utcnow()
    ...:     return default
    ...:

In [12]: foo()
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 1, 50, 50, 582885)

In [13]: foo()
Out[13]: datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 27, 1, 50, 56, 356420)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the date, you can try `datetime.date.today()` or `datetime.datetime.now().date` as long as you have the timezone configured in your settings file. You can import like `from datetime import datetime`.

However, I still think it's easier if you give the model a datetimefield if you have a model.